# Hide address bar in Progressive Web Applications

Tags: fullscreen, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

I'm developing a PWA with VueJS. I started testing my application in real devices (Add to home screen). My application is intended to be 100% height, as it displays a map as you can see:

[image]

It seems that sometimes, transitions that appear from outside the viewport height, makes the address bar appear at the top of the page.
For a PWA, I think this behaviour makes the app feel less native, and also, breaks my design (The button at bottom center and the whole map container are not visible unless the user close manually the address bar).

[image]

I tried some things I've seen in other questions:

- `window.scrollTo(0, 1);`
- `<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">`
- from [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgtadb.png).

I don't care if the app does not hide the address bar when visited in a web browser. But at least I want the address bar hidden when the app is launched as a "native" app (added to home screen).

I also tried changing `display` property in the **`manifest.json`** from `standalone` to `fullscreen` with no luck.

I know I could change the css for my button and map in order to make them "visible" when the address bar is visible, but as I said, this makes feel the app less native IMO.

Is there a solution for hidding permanently the address bar? Is it possible or it is something I have to consider in my design?

Comment: I've never seen that kind of address bar from a PWA added to Home screen from browser. It looks like Customs tabs. Are you by chance embedding your PWA in a Android native app or is it a  simple PWA added using Chrome? https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/10/using-twa

Comment: It's a PWA added to the home screen using Chrome. I've used Vuejs PWA template to build muy app. https://github.com/vuejs-templates/pwa and the app is served over HTTPS.

Comment: Are you using a custom port on your URL?

Comment: Hi! I'm not using a custom port yo serve my app. But if it has something to do, i'm using a custom `start_url` in my manifest.json other than `index.html`

Comment: It does make a difference for the Standalone window & Chrome. There is a known issue with ports on URLs. Once people switch to the standard, The standalone window opens without the address bar.

Comment: But my URL looks like `https://example.com/appName`. There is not custom port. Just, the start_url in manifest looks like `/appName/index.html`. It seems that is something else.

Comment: Yes, probably not the same as the issue with the custom port if you are not using them anywhere in your app.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

PWA app shows the address bar when you try to navigate the pages outside of `scope`. For example if you have set your scope in manifest.json file as `scope: "/my-pwa/"` then all the page url should have prefix like this: `/my-pwa/page.html`.

Comment: Have you tested It? It makes sense. I'll try to test your solution and come back here to accept your answer.

Comment: Yes, these days I am working on PWA and experienced the same behavior.

Comment: @aareeph : I have set "start_url": "/mobile_app/index.html", "scope" : "besproveninfo.com" I have tried many options but no luck. Can you please suggest the correction in scope and start_url statement

Comment: @Jasmeen since your scope is "besproveninfo.com" therefore your url should start with "/besproveninfo.com".

Answer (score 12):

On Android you need to implement a TWA (Trusted Web Activities) to enable the full-screen mode. So I recommend you to use the [PWABuilder](https://www.pwabuilder.com/) to do that. The PWABuilder already returns you a assigned APK file and a assetlink.json that you will need upload to your server into a `.well-known` folder on the root of your host: `https://www.your-domain/.well-known/assetlink.json`> That way the Android display your PWA on full screen mode.

Answer (score 8):

**TL;DR: See the last paragraph for the solution that ultimately solved it for me.**

I have had the navbar on a PWA remain, even though I tried everything, so I thought I would share everything I did, what worked, and how I solved it finally, so you won't have to search for solutions online for hours like I had to.

Extending on @alvaropaco's answer, in the .zip file you get from PWABuilder, you **must** place the `assetlink.json` file in a folder named `.well-known`, directly under your domain. It should be accessible at https://www.your-domain.com/.well-known/assetlink.json, or the navbar will not become hidden. No exceptions. Read the README.html that came with your .apk:

> ### Next steps for getting your PWA into the Google Play Store You've successfully generated a Google Play Store app package (`.apk` file)
>
> for your PWA.
>
> Your next steps:
>
> 1. Deploy `assetlinks.json` to your server.
> 2. Test your package on an Android device or Android emulator.
> 3. Upload your `apk` file to the Google Play Store.
>
> Each step is explained below.
>
> #### 1. Deploy `assetlinks.json`
>
> Your zip file contains `assetlinks.json`. This is a [digital asset links file](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/08/twas-quickstart#creating-your-asset-link-file)
> that proves you own your PWA's domain. Upload this file to your server
> at `https://example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json`. (Replace
> example.com with your PWA's URL.)
>
> > ‍♂️ *Heads up*:
> >
> > **Digital asset links are required for your PWA to load without the browser address bar**. If you're seeing a browser address bar in your
> > app on Android, your `assetlinks.json` file is missing, inaccessible,
> > or incorrect. See our [asset links helper](/Asset-links.md) to fix
> > this.

---

**If you are *not* building you app with PWABuilder; maybe using [bubblewrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@bubblewrap/cli) instead, or something else, here are some sources to help you get started building an assetlinks.json file:**

- [Trusted Web Activities Quick Start Guide](https://developers.google.com/web/android/trusted-web-activity/quick-start#creating-your-asset-link-file)
- [Removing the Browser Address Bar](https://github.com/pwa-builder/CloudAPK/blob/master/Asset-links.md)

---

#### Sidenote:

When building my app with bubblewrap, I kept getting this annoying error that wouldn't let me continue because there was a problem installing Android SDK tools:

```
C:\Users\Me\Desktop\app>bubblewrap build
,-----.        ,--.  ,--.  ,--.
|  |) /_,--.,--|  |-.|  |-.|  |,---.,--.   ,--,--.--.,--,--.,---.
|  .-.  |  ||  | .-. | .-. |  | .-. |  |.'.|  |  .--' ,-.  | .-. |
|  '--' '  ''  | `-' | `-' |  \   --|   .'.   |  |  \ '-'  | '-' '
`------' `----' `---' `---'`--'`----'--'   '--`--'   `--`--|  |-'
                                                           `--'
Installing Android Build Tools. Please, read and accept the license agreement
build Installing Build Tools
Error: Could not find or load main class com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli


cli ERROR undefined
```

###### I posted a separate [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63526264/) related to this problem.

---

### Verify assetlinks.json

To verify that assetlinks.json is correctly recognized on an Android device, run these steps: (you need to install [adb](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools) and [grep](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm), first though):

#### Debugging Digital Asset Links

After you generated your [signed APK](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#sign-apk). it can be installed into a test device, using adb:

`adb install app-release.apk`

If the verification step fails (if the address bar is still visible) it is possible to check for error messages using the Android Debug Bridge, from your OS’s terminal and with the test device connected.

`adb logcat | grep -e OriginVerifier -e digital_asset_links`

Now, make sure you app is closed completely (force stop it), and re-open it.

If it is failing you'll see `Statement failure matching fingerprint. Verification failed.` message. Therefore is important to *review* *AndroidManifest.xml* and *build.gradle* files and check if the configurations are matching with the *assetlinks.json*.

Otherwise `Verification succeeded.` message should appear.

[source](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/svgomg-twa/blob/master/README.md)

#### What if assetlinks.json *is* verified but the navbar still persists?

I was having this problem, but I finally solved it with the help of [this](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/svgomg-twa/issues/17#issuecomment-502617752) GitHub issues post. It turned out that I had the `host` parameter in `twa-manifest.json` (not `manifest.json` because I built it with bubblewrap - it has more flexibility than PWABuilder, though it only works for Android) set to `https://example.com` instead of `www.example.com` (note the `www`) where my site is *actually* hosted. **So if you build it with PWABuilder, first go to your site in the browser, click on the address bar, copy the *entire URL* (Example: [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and not https://www.example.com or https://example.com), and paste *that* into PWABuilder.**

The address bar should be gone.

Answer (score 6):

If I understand what you would like, I've found how to have proper `display: fullscreen` on android and iOS, this without any browser UI such as address bar. As said @aareeph set correctly the scope, then add this to `header` :

```html
<meta content='yes' name='apple-mobile-web-app-capable'/>
<meta content='yes' name='mobile-web-app-capable'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

My experiences on fixing the address bar display are slightly different. I used the [the steps here](https://github.com/pwa-builder/CloudAPK/blob/master/Asset-links.md) to solve.

First: I checked the assetlinks 'sha256_cert_fingerprints' property and compared to the Play Store > App Signing > App signing key certificate > SHA-256 certificate fingerprint property. They were different, so copied the Play Store value to the assetlinks.

This didn't work immediately, but I did try on another android tablet that I hadn't used before, and it worked perfect (no address bar).

I then noticed this section at the bottom of that page:

> Clearing your site's cache: If you had previously installed your PWA on an Android device, your assetlinks.json file might be cached. Uninstall isn't enough; you may have to manually clear the browser's cache for your site before Chrome detects an updated assetlinks.json file.

I went to Chrome, cleared the history, and voila, works perfect on that device now.

Answer (score 0):

To open the PWA like a native app on Android, Chrome, etc. (without the url bar)

- Ensure that the `start_url` points to the remote-entry-point of the app for ex. https://my-app.netlify.app
- Ensure that a `.well-known/assetlinks.json` file exists - for ex. we
  should be able to access https://my-app.netlify.app/.well-known/assetlinks.json.  You can generate one and add it with the help of a PWA Builder tool.