# which mobile app framework supports konva

Tags: vue.js, konvajs, react-konva, vue-konva

I understand at the current moment, react-konva is not supported in React Native environment; however, wondering if vue-konva supports mobile app?

Or if you can suggest me a way to migrate konva canvas content to an android app?

Appreciate your response.

Comment: So I've never heard of knova before today, but if you can get this to work in a web app, you can convert that to an Android/iOS app with pwabuilder.com

Comment: But that would not be really be  a *native* app. It'd basically be loading your website in the app, although that gives you the freedom to use any HTML you want, since it's rendered in the browser.

Comment: @MarsNebulaSoup, Thanks, I will surely check that out. It seems to be an interesting one to explore.

Comment: If you run into problems with your app from pwabuilder not hiding the address bar when you install in on a mobile device, check out my answer to another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63079169/8402369). I had this problem and had to search for hours online to finally figure out that the solution (although there are different causes of this problem, and hence different solutions) was so simple.

Comment: @MarsNebulaSoup Now that makes absolute sense. I will definitely check that out. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

`Konva`, `react-konva` and `vue-konva` are designed to work on the web environment. The "web enviroment" usually means just web browsers like Chrome, Firefox, Safari.

There are platforms to build mobile apps with web technologies. Probably the most popular one is PhoneGap (or Cardova).

To use `Konva` in the mobile app you have to use such a platform and make a full app with web technologies or just open a web-view (built-in browser) for Konva part.

Comment: Thanks @lavrton. Got it. I appreciate your response.