# Bubblewrap CLI error: Could not find or load main class com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, bubblewrap

When building my app with bubblewrap, I kept getting this annoying error wouldn't let me continue because there was a problem installing Android SDK tools:

```
C:\Users\Me\Desktop\app>bubblewrap build
,-----.        ,--.  ,--.  ,--.
|  |) /_,--.,--|  |-.|  |-.|  |,---.,--.   ,--,--.--.,--,--.,---.
|  .-.  |  ||  | .-. | .-. |  | .-. |  |.'.|  |  .--' ,-.  | .-. |
|  '--' '  ''  | `-' | `-' |  \   --|   .'.   |  |  \ '-'  | '-' '
`------' `----' `---' `---'`--'`----'--'   '--`--'   `--`--|  |-'
                                                           `--'
Installing Android Build Tools. Please, read and accept the license agreement
build Installing Build Tools
Error: Could not find or load main class com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli


cli ERROR undefined
```

Structure of the `.bubblewrap` directory in `C:/Users/Me/.bubblewrap`:

```
.bubblewrap/
┣ cmdline-tools/
┃ ┗ tools/
┣ openjdk/
┃ ┣ bin/
┃ ┣ include/
┃ ┣ jre/
┃ ┣ lib/
┃ ┣ sample/
┃ ┣ ASSEMBLY_EXCEPTION
┃ ┣ LICENSE
┃ ┣ release
┃ ┣ src.zip
┃ ┗ THIRD_PARTY_README
┗ config.json
```

And the content of config.json within .bubblewrap:

```
{
    "jdkPath": "C:/Users/Me/.bubblewrap/openjdk",
    "androidSdkPath": "C:/Users/Me/.bubblewrap/cmdline-tools"
}
```

More info:

- Windows 10 v2004:
- Windows Build Number: 19041.388
- Bubblewrap version: 1.4.1

Note:
I asked [this question here](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/bubblewrap/issues/266), a while back, but I found a solution elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a great deal of searching, but I finally found a solution:

I solved the problem by installing an earlier version of Android SDK tools as suggested by @krayanni in [this post](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/5304#issuecomment-623235449)  from a different repo.

> I think latest version '6200805' has some issue, even I got the same problem.
>
> Solution: Use the older sdkmanager version, please find below links for older version.
>
> Windows no installer: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-windows-4333796.zip
>
> MacOSX: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-darwin-4333796.zip
>
> Linux: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-4333796.zip

However, apparently if you unzip the files with 7zip instead of the default windows extractor, it should work fine. I haven't tried this though.

[more info here](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/bubblewrap/issues/266)