# How to hide the url in my PWA in windows?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

I turned my site into a pwa, but the slash with the URL still appears, I made some changes to my manifest.json but so far I couldn't hide it, how to do it correctly?

[image]

This is my manifest.json

```
"lang": "pt",
"dir": "ltr",
"name": "GuiaCorretorPro",
"short_name": "GuiaCorretorPro",
"icons": [
{
  "src": "https://painel.guiacorretor.com/public/favicon.png",
  "type": "image/png",
  "sizes": "512x512",
  "purpose": "maskable"
},
{
  "src": "https://painel.guiacorretor.com/public/favicon.png",
  "type": "image/png",
  "sizes": "144x144",
  "purpose": "any"
}
],
  "theme_color": "#341864",
  "background_color": "#9b67f7",
  "start_url": "/auth/login",
  "display": "standalone",
  "orientation": "portrait",
```

Comment: Does anything here enlighten you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51788623/hide-address-bar-in-progressive-web-applications

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `scope` to your manifest.json file for it

```json
"scope": "https://painel.guiacorretor.com/"
```

> The scope member is a string that defines the navigation scope of this web application's application context. It restricts what web pages can be viewed while the manifest is applied. If the user navigates outside the scope, it reverts to a normal web page inside a browser tab or window

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest/scope